# Testing SQL Server 2008 databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, memory, cpu-usage

I have a server with 32 gigs of RAM and Intel Xeon CPU (2 processors at 2.4GHz).

SQL Server 2008 is running on it with 3 or 4 databases.

The problem is that the CPU and memory has been running at full capacity and I initially thought it was multithreaded applications I was running through Visual Studio, but after shutting these down, nothing has changed. Someone suggested I do performance testing in SQL but I am not sure if this will give the answers I need.

I looked at the activity monitor and I can see which are expensive queries etc. but my question is whether these are sufficient. I need to present to my lead stats on what is causing the spike in CPU and memory and is the activity monitor results enough or do I need to use the SQL Server Profiler and run traces. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I can't speak for the CPU usage, but SQL Server is designed to be greedy with memory - it's *expected* to consume almost all of it, since it's designed to live on a server by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following Query to find out the most expensive queries on my server - originally from  [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/02/sql-server-2008-2005-find-longest-running-query-tsql/).

Hopefully it helps!

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 t.TEXT QueryName,
                       s.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,
                       s.max_elapsed_time AS MaxElapsedTime,
                       Isnull(s.total_elapsed_time / s.execution_count, 0) AS AvgElapsedTime,
                       s.creation_time AS LogCreatedOn,
                       Isnull(s.execution_count / Datediff(s, s.creation_time, Getdate()), 0) AS FrequencyPerSec
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(s.sql_handle) t
ORDER  BY s.max_elapsed_time DESC
```

Comment: thanks..was surprised at the results though, is this based on the queries that take the longest time and what exactly is execution count

Comment: the reason I ask is because I have two queries on there that are twice a day and I dont see any of the insert queries in the list

Comment: Yes, it's ordered by the amount of time they take descending. Execution count is how many times the query has been run!

As the site I linked to (where I got the query from originally) mentions, you can reset all the counters and start logging fresh by running:
`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`.

Not all the queries are mentioned of course - this is just the top 10. You can change the "TOP 10" clause at the top to another amount, or remove it completely if you wish to see all queries.